# Unescape and convert string encoding

Tags: java, date, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have to parse a String to a Date object in Java.
The string I get following the pattern `MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss z` with locale set to `French`.

The problem occures when the date is in february, august or december due to encoding of french accents. For example, I get `d&#195;&#169;c. 15 2011 16:55:38 CET` for december 15th 2011.

I can't change the way the string is created so I have to deal with the bad encoding on my side. It seems that when generated the string is badly encoded (UTF-8 content encoded as ISO 8859-1) then escapde.

For now I use :

```
stringFromXML = stringFromXML.replaceAll("&#195;&#169;", "é");
stringFromXML = stringFromXML.replaceAll("&#195;&#187;", "û");
```

It works because the only accent in french month are `é` and `û` but is there a cleaner way to unescape and convert characters?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need two steps:

1. Resolve numeric character references, for example, using `StringEscapeUtils` as suggested by Andy:

   ```
   String unescaped = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(in);
   ```
2. Fix encoding by treating characters as UTF-8 code units:

   ```
   String out = new String(unescaped.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
   ```

Comment: This solution works on my computer but on the server I get an exception `Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "aoï¿½t 04 2011 16:55:38 CEST"`. The fix for the encoding return `aoï¿½t` instead of `août`. Any idea where that come from?

Comment: Are you sure that input is the same?

Comment: The string is read from an XML file. When I open this XML in a text editor the encoding is identified as `UTF-8 without BOM`. I read the value from following field : `<wplc:field id="EffectiveDate">ao&#195;&#187;t 04 2011 16:55:38 CEST</wplc:field>`. On my computer (Windows XP, java 1.6.0_11) the value changes from `ao&#195;&#187;t` to `aoÃ»t` to `août`. On the server (RedHat 5.4, java 1.6.0_21) the value changes from `ao&#195;&#187;t` to `aoÃ»t` to `aoï¿½t`.

Comment: @YCI: Are you sure it's not a result of further processing? Try to print results of this conversion in hex, to rule out possible output problems.

Comment: You are right I have encoding issues in my log file! Turns out that the program works when only the `unescapeHTML` is executed without re-encoding the string with `new String(unescaped.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");`. That's a bit strange but it works... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You could use Apache Commons StringEscapeUtils to do this if you don't mind that dependency.

From the [JavaDoc for StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml%28java.lang.String%29):

> Unescapes a string containing entity escapes to a string containing
>   the actual Unicode characters corresponding to the escapes. Supports
>   HTML 4.0 entities.
>
> For example, the string "&lt;Fran&ccedil;ais&gt;" will become "<Français>"

It should also work with numeric entities like you have in your input.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone else is looking for the same solution as me. I was trying to decode characters that I got from okhttp (android) requests like:
`&#195;` to `Ã`

So as suggested by @axtavt, I used `StringEscapeUtils`, but to do so I added this dependency to my gradle:

```
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
```

And fixed character issues by

```
return StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml3(word);
```