# UTF-8 convertion in Java

Tags: java, android, utf-8, url-encoding

Briefly about issue:

I have a file "лл.txt". When I read it's name into String it become "%D0%BB%D0%BB.txt". Then if I want to open and read that file it fails to find it

```
// filename contains "%D0%BB%D0%BB.txt"
in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filename))); // File not found
```

but it perfectly works if I give the original name

```
in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("лл.txt"))); // ok
```

so the question is ho to get "лл.txt" from "%D0%BB%D0%BB.txt" ?
a quick search led me to this

```
byte[] bytes = str.getBytes( Charset.forName("UTF-8" ));
str = new String( bytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8") );
```

but it doesn't work for me

Comment: It seems `%D0%BB%D0%BB` is escaped code, so its not a matter of encoding but unescaping it.

Comment: And it looks like its Unicode, not UTF-8.

Comment: hi, so how can i unescape it?

Comment: sorry, i thought unicode == utf-8. i'll change the title

Comment: No, I see it really is UTF-8. Escaped UTF-8.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158707/unescape-and-convert-string-encoding

Comment: It is only weird you are reading it escaped. How exactly are you reading this file name?

Comment: public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        File file = new File(path.get(position));
        file.getPath();
}

Comment: i'm sorry that was a wrong code, this is a correct one
getIntent().getData().getEncodedPath();

Comment: Seems obvious enough. Have you tried to use getPath instead of getEncodedPath ?

Comment: yes, i just tries it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to be URL encoded with utf-8 charset. You can take cue from the following sample conversion:

```
System.out.println(URLEncoder.encode("лл.txt", "utf-8")); // Gives %D0%BB%D0%BB.txt
System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode("%D0%BB%D0%BB.txt", "utf-8")); // Gives лл.txt
```